Same Query is not getting timeout error in Query Studio but in Automation Studio
as subject saying I'm getting an timeout error from Automation studio and the same query is completely run in Query studio in very short time. (within an 1 minute)
anyone who know why this is happening, please let me know.
the Target DE has 4 Primary keys set which is SubscriberKey, JobId, BatchId and Email
and the query activity's data action is Update.
and this is the query getting an timeout error.
SELECT          
s.SubscriberKey,
s.AccountID,
s.OYBAccountID,
s.JobID,
s.ListID,
s.BatchID,
s.SubscriberID as SubscriberID,
s.EventDate as EmailSentDate,  

ts.EmailAddr as Email,
ts.view_email_url as WebURL,  
SUBSTRING(ts.EmailAddr, CHARINDEX('@', ts.EmailAddr) + 1, LEN(ts.EmailAddr) - CHARINDEX('@', ts.EmailAddr)) as Domain,

s.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID,
s.TriggeredSendCustomerKey,

o.EventDate as EmailOpenDate,
o.IsUnique as EmailOpenUnique,

c.EventDate as EmailClickDate,
c.IsUnique as EmailClickUnique,

u.[IsUnique] as Unsubscribed,
u.[EventDate] as UnsubscribedDate,

b.[BounceCategory] as BounceType,
b.[BounceSubcategory] as BounceDetail,
b.[IsUnique] as Bounced,
b.[EventDate] as BouncedDate,
(CASE WHEN b.[IsUnique] IS NOT NULL THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END) as Delivered,

cp.[IsUnique] as SpamComplaint,
cp.[EventDate] as SpamComplaintDate,

f.[IsUnique] as Forwarded,
f.[TransactionTime] as ForwardedDate,

GETDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Central America Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time' as CreatedDate
                
FROM        [_Sent] s
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        JobID,
        BatchID,
        SubID,
        EmailAddr,
        view_email_url
    FROM 
        [TechnicalSendlog]
) ts 
ON s.JobID = ts.JobID 
    AND s.BatchID = ts.BatchID 
    AND s.SubscriberID = ts.SubID

FULL OUTER JOIN [_Open] o
    ON s.[JobID] = o.[JobID] AND s.[BatchID] = o.[BatchID] AND s.[SubscriberKey] = o.[SubscriberKey] AND o.[IsUnique] = 1 
FULL OUTER JOIN [_Click] c 
    ON s.[JobID] = c.[JobID] AND s.[BatchID] = c.[BatchID] AND s.[SubscriberKey] = c.[SubscriberKey] AND c.[IsUnique] = 1
FULL OUTER JOIN [_Unsubscribe] u
    ON s.[JobID] = u.[JobID] AND s.[BatchID] = u.[BatchID] AND s.[SubscriberKey] = u.[SubscriberKey] AND u.[IsUnique] = 1
FULL OUTER JOIN [_Bounce] b
    ON s.[JobID] = b.[JobID] AND s.[BatchID] = b.[BatchID] AND s.[SubscriberKey] = b.[SubscriberKey] AND b.[IsUnique] = 1
FULL OUTER JOIN [_Complaint] cp
    ON s.[JobID] = cp.[JobID] AND s.[BatchID] = cp.[BatchID] AND s.[SubscriberKey] = cp.[SubscriberKey] AND cp.[IsUnique] = 1
FULL OUTER JOIN [_FTAF] f
    ON s.[JobID] = f.[JobID] AND s.[BatchID] = f.[BatchID] AND s.[SubscriberKey] = f.[SubscriberKey] AND f.[IsUnique] = 1
    
where      SUBSTRING(s.[SubscriberKey],1,3) != '003'

AND (
    (s.EventDate AT TIME ZONE 'Central America Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time') >= DATEADD(hour, -6, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Central America Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time'))))
    OR (o.EventDate AT TIME ZONE 'Central America Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time') >= DATEADD(hour, -6, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Central America Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time'))))
    OR (c.EventDate AT TIME ZONE 'Central America Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time') >= DATEADD(hour, -6, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Central America Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time'))))
    OR (u.EventDate AT TIME ZONE 'Central America Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time') >= DATEADD(hour, -6, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Central America Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time'))))
    OR (b.EventDate AT TIME ZONE 'Central America Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time') >= DATEADD(hour, -6, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Central America Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time'))))
    OR (cp.EventDate AT TIME ZONE 'Central America Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time') >= DATEADD(hour, -6, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Central America Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time'))))
    OR (f.TransactionTime AT TIME ZONE 'Central America Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time') >= DATEADD(hour, -6, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Central America Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time'))))
    )

and I did some test against this issue.
I cleared the TargetDE and run the query in the Automation Studio.
It don't have any timeout error, but when I re-run the query with records added to the TargetDE (around 100k records) It get timeout error with the exactly same query.
anyone who knows how to solve it. please let me know.
Thanks!

There are multiple factors that could be causing this issue:

The first thing that comes to mind is the way you're comparing the date fields. I don't think this is the most efficient method. I recommend optimising your query by following the Marketing Cloud best practices.

Another approach is to create a new target Data Extension (DE), just in case the existing DE has odd indexing or other issues.

If it still doesn't work with a new DE, keep in mind that updating takes more time than overwriting. This might be why it works in Query Studio but not through the query activity. To address this, you can create a temporary DE to receive the new data and overwrite it. Then, use a much simpler query to update the target DE from the temporary DE.



Hi! Thanks for your detailed answer. I run the ssjs activity to clear the records of targetDE  before running query. and It don't have any timeout issue still now.
